# Android and Apple pay in Ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, android-pay, applepay

I have a serious doubt in the availability of **Android pay** in **Ionic apps**. While searching for `Android pay` and `Apple pay` I got this [discussion](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/pay-with-pay-in-apple-app/21799) and this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-applepay) to integrate `Apple pay`. But no signs of `Android pay` anywhere.

So guys, if anyone of you integrated it earlier in Ionic apps, or have knowledge of any available plugin. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you get any reference link to the Android Pay implementation?

Comment: No.not yet......

Comment: Have you got any update on this? I saw Google Pay is requested through Braintree API and Braintree is supported in Ionic, I haven't tried it though.

Comment: @Joe that's helpful. Could you please try it out and tell me if it helps ?

Comment: I'm still exploring the options for my potential solution, will let you know but it might take a while

Comment: That is ok.....

Comment: We might consider using react native given our experiences. I found in another post that you can use Ionic native and link to an Android native Java library for enabling Google pay. You need to write the Java library or find an open sourced one though.

Comment: Did anyone end up trying out the Braintree implementation?